# Android fragments: AsyncTask IO error handling

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main activity which use view pager to display 3 tabs. In each tab fragment, I may call two AsyncTask classes to fetch data from the my web service. When the background task failed to connect to the web service, I would like to handle the ConnectException by closing the main activity(that has the 3 tabs) and redirect to errorActivity. What is the best way to do this?

I have set launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest file.

Currently, what I do for each AsyncTask is:

```
private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Person>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Person> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return new Fetcher().fetchPeople();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetchPeople");
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Person> people) {
            mPeople = people;
        ….
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ErrorActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(ErrorFragment.EXTRA_ERROR_MSG, ErrorFragment.MSG_UNEXPECTED_ERROR);
            startActivity(i);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
```

But the problem I am facing is having to open multiple ErrorActivity considering that the first two tabs will be called upon start up.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in your activity called `onConnectionFailed()` and in all fragments when service call fails call `getActivity()` typecaste it into your activity and call `onConnectionFailed()`.

You can also create an interface with this function, make you activity implement that function and provide the body for it, and finally pass the activity as the object of that interface to the fragments.

inside onConnectionFailed() just call `finish()`
EDIT 1:

```
onWebServiceCallFailed(){
if(!error){
Intent i = new Intent(this,
            i.putExtra(ErrorFragment.EXTRA_ERROR_MSG, ErrorFragment.MSG_UNEXPECTED_ERROR);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();
  error = true;
}
}
```

And inside activity create a `boolean error = false`

Comment: Isn't onConnectionFailed a callback for Google Api Client  OnConnectionFailedListener.??

Comment: I am talking about creating your own function in your activity. If it conflicts with some other function just give it a different name. Are facing a problem that multiple error activities are getting displayed?

Comment: Hi, I did what you said and implemented onWebServiceCallFailed(String errorMsg) in the mainActivity. In each Async::onCancelled, I called  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onWebServiceCallFailed("from method A"). But I am still opening multiple ErrorActivity.

Comment: Hi, declaring error as static variable helps. Although not the most elegant way, I do this for now.